# How much judicial bias is enough for recusal?

Tags: judge

A layman curiosity here. All I know about the courts comes from TV shows, which are, apparently, [not real very much](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/why-do-the-litigants-leave-their-paperwork-as-they-exit-on-judge-judy). However, given their original intent of educate populace about the legal system, there should be some semblance of realism, or so I hope.

Anyway, the question comes from watching several episodes of Judge Judy. She seems to have a very strong bias against young people. In more than one episode she said something like this: "How do you know that a teenager is lying? His lips move."

So she affirmed multiple times in several unrelated episodes that she does not trust teenagers' words for no reason other than being teenagers. Bias of that magnitude obviously puts teenage litigants at strong disadvantage. However, Judge Judy has never recused herself in trials (or mediations, whatever they are) on the basis of her own bias.

Thus the question: would unapologetic and openly professed judicial bias like that be tolerated in real courts? Would the party being biased against be able to push judicial recusal?

Comment: “However, given their original intent of educate populace about the legal system” — That’s not and has never been the intent of anything but actual documentaries. The intent of Judge Judy, Law and Order, and all other non-documentaries is to entertain people so that they watch the show. Judge Judy entertains people through her character (and yes, she does almost certainly play to the cameras because that’s part of her job), so comments in line with that character would be a weird reason to not take the case.

Comment: @cpast, I understand that. What's your opinion on the question whether such judicial behavior would be tolerated in real courtroom? If a real judge would repeatedly announce that all teens are liars and she would never believe a teenager's word, would such a judge be allowed to adjudicate a case involving a teenager or would have to recuse herself because of the prejudice against teens?